# How to fetch Shadow Copies of a SMB Share?

Tags: python, smb, virtual-shadow-copies

How can I fetch the list of Shadow Copies available for a specific remote SMB URI with Python?
(OS is Windows if win32api is required.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [DiskShadow](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772172.aspx), with the [**`list`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753848.aspx) command:

> `list shadows {all | set <SetID> | id <ShadowID>}`

Comment: I prefer to do it with API or SMB call and not though an external tool.

Comment: Oh. Well, put that in the question. Maybe there's another way to do it. [DiskShadow](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772172.aspx) is the standard tool from Microsoft.